# What parts of the javascript code can an XSS attack access?

Tags: xss, javascript, jwt

I understand that XSS attacks can access all globals (like cookies, storage, etc) within the context of the running javascript code, but I would like to understand if they could also have access to any in memory variables as well?

For example, there are some suggestions to keep the JWT in memory (and refresh it silently with the provider on page refresh). I would like to understand whether this would be susceptible to XSS or not, in what scenarios would this info not be accessible to an XSS attack?

For example, if i keep it in `window.jwt`, I believe it would be accessible, but if it is kept in, say, React component state, or in a closure, would it still be accessible or not?

Even if not accessible directly, since we would be sending this token with API calls in a header, would it still be possible to read the headers being sent out in the API calls and get the token value?

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies things a little bit, and is quite in line with what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

#### XSS can access anything a script can.

Why? Because XSS injected scripts are indistinguishable from other scripts. If you keep a JWT in memory, XSS can access and exfiltrate it.

#### How can you protect your token?

Store it in a cookie with the `HTTPOnly` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assume that every variable that you create, every code on the client side can be modified or read by the attacker in case of an XSS attack.

For example, if the attacker is looking for a token that is sent in an API call, he can simply hook/rewrite the function that is used for making the API call at runtime and extract the token before it is sent.